# Is Paging efficient in Objectionjs orm?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, objection.js

On every paged query, I see 2 query one is query with limit and offset. One is count.

Does this have any performance issues on every request when there are multiple joins?

Answer (score 1):

`JOINs` may or may not be a problem.  It depends on whether the `JOIN` must be completed before doing the pagination.

If the Optimizer cannot get to the `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` soon enough, it will have to generate all the possible rows, sort them, skip over `OFFSET` rows, then finally deliver `LIMIT` rows.

If the Optimizer can do better, then the first page is fast; the second page is twice as slow; etc.  Each page is slower and slower because of having to step over all the previous pages.

That is, `OFFSET` is the real problem.  It is better to "remember where you left off".

More discussion (aimed at MySQL; it may be awkward to map the fix to your framework layer):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination